# Prove that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \cal{S}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Here $\cal{S}$ is the Schwartz Class defined as the set of functions $\cal{S}:=\{u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n):\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|x|^j)|D^\alpha|\leq \infty,\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0,\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^n\}$. Can someone help me with the prove of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I thing you meant "$< \infty$" and not "$\leqslant \infty$" because it would be the entire smooth functions class. Moreover, you forgot to put $u$ after $D^{\alpha}$.

Then : think of what exactly means $C^{\infty}_c$ ? I think it stands for smooth functions with compact support right ? Show that if $f$ is smooth and has compact support, $D^{\alpha}f$ is with compact support too (hint : $f$ is equal to $0$ outside its support : what could be its derivative outside the support then ?).
Second hint : show that a continuous function with compact support is bounded !